# Spring Integration file processing send it to http

Tags: java, spring, rest, soa, spring-integration

I have some points to resolve it in spring integration, I'm kind of newbie in spring integration.

The scenario is to process three dbf files and extract the data and send it to HTTP rest service as JSON  if there is no response from that service during 3 mins should wait 10 mins and attempt again. The rest service will reply with json.

now I have three to four things I can't solve it:

1. I need to read the reply from rest service and depend on that reply decide either to retry or to finish the process. (beside if I send message to rest and no response should also retry)
2. I need to get multiple files from dynamic folder names for example ({wherever}/20140101/HERE WILL FIND THE THREE DBF FILES). there is any possibility to make folder name as pattern or as date with certain format? and the file adapter can process many files or files by file.
3. there is any possibility to process dbf files through spring integration and transform it to json

below my spring integration configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task">


<int:service-activator input-channel="filesInChannelDBF"
    output-channel="requestChannel" >
    <bean class="com.mm.integration.serviceactivator.FileProcessor" />
</int:service-activator>


<int:channel id="requestChannel" />



<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel"
    url="http://localhost:8090/receiveGateway" http-method="POST" />

<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesInChannelDBF"
    directory="file:input" filename-pattern="FILENAME*">
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-rate="100" task-executor="executor" />

</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="10" />

</beans>
```

and here my pom:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-  4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mm.integration</groupId>
  <artifactId>XXXX</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.9.RELEASE</version>
   </parent>
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and here my spring entry point.

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableIntegration
@ImportResource("classpath:spring/config/concurrentFileProcessing-config.xml")
public class MainApp {

    @RequestMapping(value="/receiveGateway" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String testGateway(String jSon){

        System.out.println("Starting process the message [reciveing]");

        return "{HelloMessage: \"Hello\"}";
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1- I need to read the reply from rest service and depend on that reply decide either to retry or to finish the process.

Any `processor` (e.g. `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`) endpoint can be configured with `<request-handler-advice-chain>`. And there is out-of-the-box advices for you: `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` and `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`. You can specify the retry advice as first one and expression as the second. With the last you can make some decision to throw or not an exception to initiate that wrapping retry. Because this one can retry only on exception. It would be better than get deal with `RetryContext` to have an ability to specify the custom `RetryPolicy` independently of exceptions.

In addition consider to use `request-factory` with timeout options to get deal with `no response` case.

> 2- I need to get multiple files from dynamic folder names for example ({wherever}/20140101/HERE WILL FIND THE THREE DBF FILES).

Consider to use `RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner` to scan those timestamp directories from the specified root dir. From other side you even can provide any `DirectoryScanner` implementation to achieve the requiremnts.

> 3- there is any possibility to process dbf files through spring integration and transform it to json

No, Spring Integration doesn't support that feature. You can consider to use some existing tool to read DBF (https://github.com/iryndin/jdbf) and then build JSON  manually.

From other side feel free to contribute it back to the framework as an [extension](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions) with appropriate adapters.

Comment: Thanks for you response can you give me an  modified version of my spring configuration with your suggestion?

Comment: No, it is out of my responsibility. Take a look to the docs http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/ and our samples: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples

Comment: ok at least guide me how to put three files with that scanner and I'll take care about the rest

Comment: Looking at your requirements `{wherever}/20140101/HERE WILL FIND THE THREE DBF FILES`, there is just enough to use a default `RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner` and leave others options (`directory="file:input" filename-pattern="FILENAME*"`) as is. See its source code: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner.java

Comment: bu there is alot of files under the folder with same prefix for example GNDXXXX1.dbf, GNDXXXX2.dbf , GNDXXXX3 and also there is other file which i don't need to use start with GND. how can solve that issue?

Comment: You always can provide your custom `FileListFilter`. `DirectoryScanner` just prepare a set of files from dirs, but after that a `FileListFilter` starts to work to filter undesiread files.

Comment: I made custom filter but I faced another issue which they consider each files will send request to http. what I need here to collect files and send one http request

Comment: That is another question and it is related to the `aggregator`. Don't remeber already similar questions here on SO, but you always can ask a new one and we'll try to help you with that as well.

Comment: yes I fix it through creating aggregator! I have to close this question because it drive us to many question. one last question please which is face after creating the aggregator, now my senario to get files under leaf folder and some of leaf folder means it will have multiple folder with different file to process. in current situation it only process the first folder and send it to http gateway but the remain folders is not sending any message, there is anyway to solve that? I think I will face alot of issue once I start with retry http which is the first point

Comment: I found the issue but I didn't find a solution. because I choose `RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner` its consider all the sub folder as a one message! but the scenario is every folder its a separate message and the folder sometimes is not exist will be created later
how can do such scenario?

Comment: If you have such a complex dir tree, consider to use several `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>` for the same `channel`

Comment: But folders not fixed its dynamic created

Comment: So, custom `DirectoryScanner` should help here.

Comment: sorry for really long discussion but what I face now is the inbound file reading all the files which is fine but after the aggregate send message for certain number files its stop and don't send the remain ? do you think I need transaction for that ? or `DirectoryScanner` will help?

Comment: As I said before: `aggregator` is a separate question and it isn't so simple to `group` messages from any `inbound-channel-adapter`.

Comment: I doubt its related to aggregator, let me again repeate what happened with me to see if its related to aggregator or not. I wan to recursive the file inside the internal folder each folder has four files I combine it and send the message. but each folder here is separate message

Comment: Even if you scan folder for several files at once the `FileReadingMessageSource` emits them one by one as separate messages. So, I guess you group them to the single message using aggregator. You say that aggregator doesn't want to release upcoming groups, just only the first one. So, it should be configured with `expire-groups-upon-completion="true"` to remove complete groups and be ready to form a new one. Hence it is a question to the aggregator, because you use the same `correlationKey` for all groups.